# Norms and Derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

Does the derivative of a function between normed vector spaces $f:X\to Y$ depend on the norms $\|\cdot \|_X$ and $\|\cdot \|_Y$? Or can I just assume that all results from calculus still hold regardless of the norm?

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ are finite-dimensional, then all norms on these spaces generate identical topologies. However, two norms on an infinite-dimensional linear space are not necessarily equivalent. Consequently, if $X$ and $Y$ are infinite-dimensional, then a bounded linear operator from $X$ to $Y$ with respect to one set of norms may not be bounded with respect to a different set.